# Saving specific areas of a filename

Tags: autohotkey

I have a list of pdf files in this format  "123 - Test - English.pdf".  I want to be able to set "111", "Test" and "English.pdf" in their own individual variables.  I tried running the code below but I don't think it accounts for multiple dashes "-". How can I do this? Please help Thanks in advance.

```
    Loop,C:\My Documents\Notes\*.pdf, 0, 0
    {
    NewVariable = Trim(Substr(A_LoopFileName,1, Instr(A_LoopFileName, "-")-1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a parse loop to get your variables. The following loops through values between the dashes and removes the whitespace.

```
FileName = Test - file - name.pdf
Loop, parse, FileName, `-
    MyVar%A_Index% := RegExReplace(A_LoopField, A_Space, "")

msgbox % Myvar1 "`n" Myvar2 "`n" MyVar3
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I don't know if it was a typo, but if you use a `{` under your loop statement, you also need to close it.  If your next statement is just one line, you don't need any brackets at all.

Second, if you just use `=` then your code will output as just that very code text.  You need to use a `:=`

Third, your present code, if coded correctly would result in this:

```
somepdffile.pd
```

if it found any pdf files without a dash.  `Instr()` will return the position of a dash.  If there is no dash, it returns `0` - in which case, your `substr()` statement will add `0` and your `-1` which adds up to `-1` and if you use a negative number with `substr()`, it will search from the end of the string instead of the beginning - which is why your string would get cut off.

```
Loop, C:\My Documents\Notes\*.pdf, 0, 0
{
    ;look at the docs (http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/) for `substr`
}
```

So there is an explanation of why your code doesn't work.  To get it to do what you want to do, can you explain a bit more as to how you want `NewVariable` to look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
; here is another way (via RegExMatch)
src:="123 - Test - English.pdf", pat:="[^\s|-]+"
While, mPos:=RegExMatch(src, pat, match, mPos ? mPos+StrLen(match):1)
   match%A_Index%:=match
MsgBox, 262144, % "result", % match1 ", "match2 ", "match3
```